# How to build a regular expression in a URL

Tags: regex

I want build a reg expression inside a URL that would match any 3 characters after the "person-":

```
/mysite/portraits/person-abc/
/mysite/portraits/person-xyz/
/mysite/portraits/person-123/
```

Would this be what I need?

```
/mysite/portraits/person-*/
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is what you'll be needing:

```
(.{3})/$
```

Note that you've to escape `/` to suit your language of choice

Group 1 will contain those three characters.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with following regex:

```
person-([a-z0-9]{3})/$
```

To match any character - not only alphanumeric, use `.` as @Amit Joki has posted.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to escape your slashes
- You need to put add a dot before your `*` operator (here, you're looking for multiples dashes)
- You can replace `*` by `{3,}` to look for 3 or more characters
- You can use `^$` to define boundaries

```
/^\/mysite\/portraits\/person-.{3,}\/$/
```

[image]

If you want to capture the dynamic part, add parenthesis :

```
/^\/mysite\/portraits\/person-(.{3,})\/$/
```

Comment: Could you share what you used to generate the Regex flowchart?

Comment: @Xiaoy312 You can generate it via [Regexper](http://www.regexper.com/) or [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) for example.